# Calculate the number of different words, where $0$ appears an even number of times.

Tags: combinatorics

Let the set of words with an even length $n$ from the alphabet: $\{ 0,1,2\}$.

Calculate the number of different words, where $0$ appears an even number of times.

For example, for $n=6$ , the words $121212,001212,000000$ are allowed,but the word $100011$ is not allowed.

My idea is:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n-2}{2}} \binom{n}{2k} \cdot \binom{n-2k}{2}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Would it be $\binom{n-2k}{2}$ or $2^{n-2k}$? because $1,2$ can repeat right? Otherwise it looks okay.

Comment: What do you mean? Since the words that I have written that are allowed contain $1$ and $2$ more than once, $1,2$ can repeat. So, is my idea correct?

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay Could you explain me the formula that you have written?

Answer (score 5):

We define the two following functions: o(n)= number of words with $n$ letters where there is an odd number of $0$'s. $e(n)$=number of words with $n$ letters where there is an even number of $0$'s. It is clear $o(n)+e(n)=3^n$.We also know  $e(n+1)=2e(n)+o(n)=3^n+e(n).$

Let us look at the first few values of $e(n):2,5,14,41,122$

$e(1)=2=1+(1)$

$e(2)=5=1+(1+3)$

$e(3)=14=1+(1+3+9)$

$e(4)=41=1+(1+3+9+27)$

So in general we have $e(n)=1+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}3^i$ which using the formula for geometric sum gives us $e(n)=\frac{3^n-1}{2}+1$

Comment: And is the formula that I have written in my first post correct?

Comment: Hmm I would say it should be $\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n-2}{2}} \binom{n}{2k} \cdot 2^{n-2k}$ Since you can make the remaining characters into whatever you want using the digits 2 and 3

Comment: A ok!!!I got it!!!Thank you!!! :-)

Comment: However, it might be possible to get something nicer out of my approach, only I don't know enough generating functions to be sure, I'm working on it.

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, I managed to turn it into something pretty sweet, hope you like it.

Comment: You can classify the elements of $e(n+1)$ into three types, the ones that end with a $0$ (there are $o(n)$ of these).The ones that end with a $1$  (there are $e(n)$ of these)and the ones that end with a $2$ (there are $e(n)$ of these. This gives us a total of $2e(n)+o(n)$

Comment: Nice. This also follows from Binomial expansion of $(2+1)^n$.

Comment: @MaryStar does this answer not satisfy you?

Answer (score 3):

I want to say that your formula should be $\sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{n}{2k}2^{n-2k}$ because once you've chosen $2k$ positions out of $n$ for placing $0$'s in one of the $\binom{n}{2k}$ in the rest of the $(n-2k)$ places, at each place you can put a $1$ or a $2$ in $2$ ways which gives you a total of $2^{n-2k}$ ways.

In general if you have an alphabet of size $l$ and you want the number of $n$ length words that have only even number of a particular alphabet (like $0$ here) then using the same logic that was used to get your answer, you get the number as $$\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}(l-1)^{n-2k}=\binom{n}{0}(l-1)^{n}+\binom{n}{2}(l-1)^{n-2}+\cdots+\binom{n}{2\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(l-1)^{n-2\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$$ Now, $$l^n=\binom{n}{0}(l-1)^n+\binom{n}{1}(l-1)^{n-1}+\cdots+\binom{n}{n}\\ (l-2)^n=\binom{n}{0}(l-1)^n-\binom{n}{1}(l-1)^{n-1}+\cdots+(-1)^n\binom{n}{n}\\ $$ So the desired number is $$\frac{l^n+(l-2)^n}{2}$$

Comment: Why is it $\frac{l^n+(l-2)^n}{2}$?

Answer (score 3):

Another cool way is by using Generating functions. If you write the automata that accepts that kind of String and use the Schützenberger theorem, you can come up with it easily. i.e. 
$\frac{1-5x^2}{1-10x^2+9x^4}$ And from them, you got the following recursion
$a_0=1,a_1=0,a_2=5,a_3=0$
$a_n=10a_{n-2}-9a_{n-4}$ for $n\geq4$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is by using exponential generating function:

Since $0$ appears even number of times and $1,2$ has no restriction, the  egf is:

\begin{align*}
  G(x) &= \left(1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots\right)\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots\right)^2 \\
  &= \left(\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}\right)e^{2x} \\
  &= \frac{e^{3x}+e^{x}}{2}
\end{align*}
and $$\left[\frac{x^n}{n!}\right]G(x) = \frac{3^n+1}{2}$$

Comment: Why is it: $\left[\frac{x^n}{n!}\right]G(x) = \frac{3^n+1}{2}$? why multiply the LHS by $\left[\frac{x^n}{n!}\right]$ and where did the $e$ go?

Answer (score 0):

The recurrence relation for this problem will be
$$A_n = A_{n-1} + 3^{n-1} ; n>1 $$

$$A_1 = 2$$

Solve this recurrence equation using homogeneous and particular solution method.
You will get the answer: $$(3^n + 1)/2$$